# Falcon 9 Stage-1 Reentry Burn: Throttle Setting, Duration?

Tags: launch, falcon-9, launch-sequence

How long does stage 1 of Falcon 9 fire its engines during its reentry burn, and what throttle setting do they use? Also, is it known how much fuel is left at MECO? Thanks if you know and can share!